# how i can do a crontab as user on raspbian?

Tags: cron, raspbian

I'm on a raspberry pi, with rasbpian !
I'm trying to install a new crontab for execute an basic script. This one will take a picture from webcam with vlc.

I want to do this every minute but i can't edit my crontab user (crontab -e), only the sudo crontab... Or vlc must do execute without root !

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ crontab -e
crontabs/pi/: fdopen: Permission denied
```

Every body know how i can do ?

This is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

cvlc -I dummy v4l2:///dev/video0 --video-filter scene --no-audio --scene-path $

date > ~/webcam/date.txt
```

And this is my crontab for root, which not work :

```
* * * * * sh image.sh
```

Comment: Have you set a password for sudo yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting permission denied for `crontab -e`, but if you use `sudo crontab -e -u pi`, then you will be able to open the crontab for the pi user with sudo.

Incidentally, you probably need to specify a direct path for `image.sh`. Otherwise the script won't be able to find it.

Comment: Oh thanks! I tried sudo -u pi and with the direct path but not both!
It's good now, my script work every minute but it's not doing what i want...
When I execute my script in terminal with ./image.sh it's good, the picture is taken but not when the crontab execute the script... 
howewer it's the same...