# python wait for input and upload file

Tags: python, input, ftp

I have two python scripts that I'd like to consolidate into one.

My environment is Raspberry Pi Raspbian

The first python script waits for an input string

```
keepalive = True

while keepalive:

    rfMedia = raw_input("Waiting string... ")
    with open(filename, "a+") as logfile:
                logfile.write(str(rfMedia )
wend
```

The second does upload a list of the inputted data to my ftp site using pythons ftplib.

How would one allow the first script to run and continuously collect data but every 30 minutes run the ftp function?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that I can think of is to have your second script run in background, in a continuous loop with a sleep. Every 30 min it would read a file and load the content of the file. Ideally there would be a cron job doing this for you but I don't know much about RPi environment right now.

```
import time

keepalive = True
count = 0 

while keepalive:
  time.sleep(2)
  print 'hello'
  # upload file content
  count += 1
  if count >= 5:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [crontab](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) which runs commands on a certain interval(every day, week, etc.)

to edit your crontab use the following command:

`crontab -e`

Then to run the ftp script every 30 minutes add a line similar to the following to your crontab.

`0,30 * * * * command to start ftp script goes here`

This stackoverflow thread might also come in handy: [how can I do a crontab as a user on raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787350/how-i-can-do-a-crontab-as-user-on-raspbian)

hope that helps.